# Limit print output to 1 statement per decimal place in Python if

Tags: python

Hard to explain as title.
I am downloading a file and using a modified version of the progress bar here: https://gist.github.com/somada141/b3c21f7462b7f237e522

I want to only show increments such as 10% --- 20% --- etc, however the code is adjusted to show decimal places, meaning the default output will be 10.12% 10.45% 10.67% 10.89%.

So even if I do an if statement and match against 10, I end up with 10% printing 4 times as all the above match to 10.

Full code

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open("myfile.zip", "wb") as local_file:
     local_file.write(self.chunk_read(response, report_hook=self.chunk_report))

def chunk_report(self, bytes_so_far, chunk_size, total_size):
    percent = round(float(bytes_so_far) / total_size * 100))

    if percent == 10:
        print("%0.0f%%\r" % (percent))
    elif percent == 20:
        print("%0.0f%%\r" % (percent))
    elif percent == 30:
        print("%0.0f%%\r" % (percent))

    if bytes_so_far >= total_size:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')

def chunk_read(self, response, chunk_size=8192, report_hook=None):
    total_size = response.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
    total_size = int(total_size)
    bytes_so_far = 0
    data = []

    while 1:
        chunk = response.read(chunk_size)
        bytes_so_far += len(chunk)

        if not chunk:
            break

        data += chunk
        if report_hook:
            report_hook(bytes_so_far, chunk_size, total_size)

    return "".join(data)
```

This gives the output:

```
10%
10%
10%
10%
20%
20%
20%
20%
```

I am looking to only print out 10%, 20% once.

EDIT:
Based on joaquin's answer, fully working code is as follows:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open("myfile.zip", "wb") as local_file:
 local_file.write(self.chunk_read(response, report_hook=self.chunk_report))


def chunk_report(self, bytes_so_far, chunk_size, total_size, status):
    percent = float(bytes_so_far) / total_size
    percent = round(percent*100)
    if percent >= status:
        print("%0.0f%%\r" % (percent))
        status += 10
    return status

    if bytes_so_far >= total_size:
        print('\n')


def chunk_read(self, response, chunk_size=8192, report_hook=None):
    total_size = response.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
    total_size = int(total_size)
    bytes_so_far = 0
    data = []
    status = 0

    while 1:
        chunk = response.read(chunk_size)
        bytes_so_far += len(chunk)

        if not chunk:
            break

        data += chunk
        if report_hook:
            status = report_hook(bytes_so_far, chunk_size, total_size, status)

    return "".join(data)
```

Comment: use `if---elif--else`

Comment: What do you mean 'once'? Your code as is will print one line, max. Do you have a loop?

Comment: Save the current percent (rounded to integer) in a variable (old_percent). In the next pass check if the new value rounded to integer is higher than old_percent. If yes, print it and update old_percent.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank the code in the Git keeps looping until the download is complete. only posted the relevant parts here of the issue I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have and example that produces 10%....100% without the need for the `if` series

```
target_percent = 10
total_size = 1000
for bytes_so_far in range(1, 1000):
    percent = float(bytes_so_far) / total_size
    percent = round(percent*100)

    if percent >= target_percent:
        print("%0.0f%%\r" % (percent))
        target_percent += 10
```

you get:

```
10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
100%
```

This can be organized inside a function:

```
def get_percent(bytes_so_far, total_size, status):
    percent = float(bytes_so_far) / total_size
    percent = round(percent*100)

    if percent >= status:
        print("%0.0f%%\r" % (percent))
        status += 10
    return status
```

If we mock a repeated call to this function:

```
size = 1000
status = 10
for bytes_so_far in range(1, 1000):
    status = get_percent(bytes_so_far, size, status)
```

we get again:

```
10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
100%
```

Comment: due to the repeated calls to the def to get the download status, this just repeats multiple times, `10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
100%
10%
20%
30%
40%
50%
60%
70%
80%
90%
100%`

Comment: @jerrythebum The original question was about repeating the percentages due to the rounding of floats to the same integer. Now you are refering to a different problem. Please modify your post with the minimal code to reproduce the problem. The behaviour you comment here can not be predicted from the code you posted.

Comment: @jerrythebum I confirm my code works perfect if implemented in your code. Note that chunk_report must have `status` as a parameter and also must return/update `status` after each call.